# How to replace last n values of a row with zero

Tags: pandas

I want to replace last 2 values of one of the column with zero. I understand for NaN values, I am able to use .fillna(0), but I would like to replace row 6 value of the last column as well.

```
Weight  Name    Age d_id_max    
0   45  Sam     14  2   
1   88  Andrea  25  1   
2   56  Alex    55  1   
3   15  Robin   8   3   
4   71  Kia     21  3   
5   44  Sia     43  2   
6   54  Ryan    45  1   
7   34  Dimi    65  NaN
```

df.drop(df.tail(2).index,inplace=True)

```
 Weight Name    Age  d_id_max   
0   45  Sam     14  2   
1   88  Andrea  25  1   
2   56  Alex    55  1   
3   15  Robin   8   3   
4   71  Kia     21  3   
5   44  Sia     43  2   
6   54  Ryan    45  0
7   34  Dimi    65  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Before pandas 0.20.0 (long time) it was job for `ix`, but [now it is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated). So you can use:

[`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for get last rows and also [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions of column `d_id_max`:

```
df.iloc[-2:, df.columns.get_loc('d_id_max')] = 0
print (df)
   Weight    Name  Age  d_id_max
0      45     Sam   14       2.0
1      88  Andrea   25       1.0
2      56    Alex   55       1.0
3      15   Robin    8       3.0
4      71     Kia   21       3.0
5      44     Sia   43       2.0
6      54    Ryan   45       0.0
7      34    Dimi   65       0.0
```

Or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with indexing index values:

```
df.loc[df.index[-2:], 'd_id_max'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.iloc` and `get_loc`

```
df.iloc[[-1,-2], df.columns.get_loc('d_id_max')] = 0

Out[232]:
   Weight    Name  Age  d_id_max
0      45     Sam   14       2.0
1      88  Andrea   25       1.0
2      56    Alex   55       1.0
3      15   Robin    8       3.0
4      71     Kia   21       3.0
5      44     Sia   43       2.0
6      54    Ryan   45       0.0
7      34    Dimi   65       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['d_id_max'].iloc[-2:] = 0



    Weight    Name  Age  d_id_max
0      45     Sam   14       2.0
1      88  Andrea   25       1.0
2      56    Alex   55       1.0
3      15   Robin    8       3.0
4      71     Kia   21       3.0
5      44     Sia   43       2.0
6      54    Ryan   45       0.0
7      34    Dimi   65       0.0
```